# Exploring an equation's solution space with Manipulate

Tags: equation-solving, manipulate

I have the following simple `Manipulate` code that I use for solving an equation in two stages. In the first stage I identify the initial values `{ivX, ivY}` for the solver, and in the second stage the equation is solved for different values of the parameters `{a, b}`.

```
Manipulate[
  FindRoot[{-a + Exp[x] == y, ((a - b y) == x)}, {{x, ivX}, {y, ivY}}],
  {{ivX, 1}, 1, 5},
  {{ivY, 2}, 1, 5},
  {{a, 1}, -10, 10},
  {{b, 1}, -10, 10}]
```

The above code works for the initially given values `{ivX = 1, ivY = 2}`, but giving other values tp `ivX` and `ivY` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Can you help me to finding what is going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? If I modify `a` and `b` the solution changes. It seems like `ivX` and `ivY` simply converge on the same point for all initial conditions in that range.

Comment: @Carl Lange: I will try it with a function converging multiple points to see if it really works. In my example, you are right I think. It converges to the same point. Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Following Carl Lange's comment above, I changed the original function in `Manipulate` as follows:

```
Manipulate[
FindRoot[{-a + Exp[x]^4 == y, ((a - b y) == x)}, {{x, ivX}, {y, ivY}}],
{{ivX, 1}, -100, 100},
{{ivY, 2}, -100, 100},
{{a, 1}, -10, 10},
{{b, 1}, -10, 10}
]
```

Experiemnting with different intitial values for `{ivX, ivY}` indeed gives me the answer, which is the answer given above by Carl Lange.